# put file from local to hadoop environment

Tags: hadoop

Note: I have read all earlier posts on stackoverflow related to this scenario but couldn't find any helpful

I'm learning hadoop and facing some stucks while playing around.

1) After connected to hadoop when I check pwd, it showes /home/hduser. So it means I'm in hduser dir which is my user as well for hadoop environment. When I create a dir using below command, dir gets created.

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/
```

My question is, Why am not able to see that dir (user) under path /home/hduser from terminal but on http://localhost:50070/explorer.html#/user ?

2) Under my root two exists, One is Jon and second one is hduser.
   There is a file that I have created in user Jon at location /home/Jon and I want to put this file into hduser under /user directory.
   When I put his file using below command

```
hadoop fs -put /home/Jon/test.txt /user
```

Get an error like this

```
17/06/04 21:33:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
put: `/home/Jon/test.txt': No such file or directory
```

Note: I have given permissions as well from root in visudo file like this

```
Jon ALL(ALL:ALL) ALL
hduser ALL(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

But I am still unable to do that put from local to hduser. When I create a file in hadoop environment under dir /home/hduser then I am easily able to copy file from there to /user dir

Could anyone help me to go through these stucks...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > My question is, Why am not able to see that dir (user) under path /home/hduser from terminal but on http://localhost:50070/explorer.html#/user ?

`HDFS` and `linux file system` are two different ways of managing files and directories. `HDFS` needs `namenode` and `datanode` to be alive to view the files stored in `HDFS`. `Namenode` stores all the metadata of data stored in `datanode`. They are stored in local file system but in different format that `HDFS` can only read it.

`/user` is not exactly the local path but the path of HDFS (HDFS virtual file system).

> > Get an error like this
> >     17/06/04 21:33:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
> >     put: `/home/Jon/test.txt': No such file or directory

Generally above error is displayed when a file doesn't exists on local file system. I tried it myself and it works without any errors. Its really strange that its not working for you

What you can do is try to see if the file really exists. If it does then try

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -put /home/Jon/test.txt /user
```

If it still doesn't work then try changing the file permission of `/user` of `HDFS`

```
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user
```

Comment: thanks for your response, now its much cleared the doiubut and am able to move file as well. Secondly, I had installed haddop on my system from this website http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php..so all dir structures would be same..could you tell please where I can see dir /user from terminal when namenode and datanodes are up. I agree that that can be read by HDFS only but they must located somewhere in other format like binary...!!

Comment: you can do `hadoop fs -ls /user` to see hadoop files from terminal if `namenode` and `datanode` are up. All are linux commands but with hadoop